# Google App Engine Python WebApp framework supported self.error() codes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-error, webob

I know we can return errors to requests by calling `self.error(http_error_code_here)`. However, there are some error codes that don't seem to be supported. "Unsupported error code" comes out when I use error code 510.

I used http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes as a reference for the error codes I am using.

What http error codes are currently supported by the GAE Python WebApp Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the *supported* status codes in

```
google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py
```

around line 270.

```
__HTTP_STATUS_MESSAGES = {
  100: 'Continue',
  101: 'Switching Protocols',
  200: 'OK',
  201: 'Created',
  202: 'Accepted',
  203: 'Non-Authoritative Information',
  204: 'No Content',
  205: 'Reset Content',
  206: 'Partial Content',
```

Splitted for easier browsing.

```
  300: 'Multiple Choices',
  301: 'Moved Permanently',
  302: 'Moved Temporarily',
  303: 'See Other',
  304: 'Not Modified',
  305: 'Use Proxy',
  306: 'Unused',
  307: 'Temporary Redirect',
  400: 'Bad Request',
  401: 'Unauthorized',
  402: 'Payment Required',
  403: 'Forbidden',
  404: 'Not Found',
  405: 'Method Not Allowed',
  406: 'Not Acceptable',
  407: 'Proxy Authentication Required',
  408: 'Request Time-out',
  409: 'Conflict',
  410: 'Gone',
  411: 'Length Required',
  412: 'Precondition Failed',
  413: 'Request Entity Too Large',
  414: 'Request-URI Too Large',
  415: 'Unsupported Media Type',
  416: 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
  417: 'Expectation Failed',
  500: 'Internal Server Error',
  501: 'Not Implemented',
  502: 'Bad Gateway',
  503: 'Service Unavailable',
  504: 'Gateway Time-out',
  505: 'HTTP Version not supported'
}
```